# Jade Case Statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm trying to use a case statement in a Jade template to set the background colour on a table row, but I am getting an error which I can't seem to pin down.

This is the code:

```
each photog, i in thelist.ptlist
    case photog.currentStatus
        when "green": tr(style="background-color:#9f9")
        when "amber": tr(style="background-color:#ff9")
        when "red": tr(style="background-color:#f99")
        default: tr(style="background-color:#99f")
        td.
            #{photog.currentStatus}
```

The error I am getting is "Unexpected token 'tag', expected 'when', 'default' or 'newline'" indicating the "td." I tried adding a blan line before the td, but I get exactly the same error.

I have tried the slight variants in layout/syntax that the documentation gives, but to no avail. Would someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I believe the error is caused by td tag which makes rendering engine think it belongs to case statement. You have to move it outside the case statement.

Comment: That's solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The   `td` tag is aligned with the default thus making it inherited by case statement. Put   `td` outside the case by removing the extra whitespaces.